# Read allure.properties file from specific location

Tags: maven, properties, report, allure

I need to define multiple **allure.properties** files (because of different tmslink and issue patterns), for different projects, within the same testing framework.

I need to tell somehow Allure to load the properties based on an environment variable (**-Dproject=team1**)

Does anyone know if I can specify to allure from where to take the file? The current implementation is to rad it from declared resources folder.

```
Project
   -main
   -test
   -resources
     - allure.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven profiles for this.

Here is the documentation

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

A different profile would refer to a different properties file.

Build different profiles with -P